# VS studio won't debug after renaming project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using vs studio 2022 making a vb.net project, it was still beta so I used the default name (WinFormsApp).
after finishing the project I changed the name via solution explorer (changed both solution and project names).

Now when I publish the project it has no problem. However, **when I debug from inside the vs studio it runs the last version of the app before changing its name.**

In other words now to test any addition to the coding or designing, I have to publish then test on the published version instead of simply clicking 'debug

I checked for assembly names, saved and even built solution and project but still runs an out-datesd version (last version before changing the name)

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: How EXACTLY are you starting the debugger? What happens if you right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select *Debug -> Start New Instance*?

Comment: It still loaded the old version when I debugged starting a new instance

Comment: and I used to debug through the debug menu -> start debugging or simply the green arrow just below it

Comment: If you add a new project and make it the startup project, can you debug that? I'm wondering whether the issue is at the solution or project level. If you can debug a new project, I'd probably suggest naming the old project back again, adding a new project with the desired name, dragging the items from the old project to the new in the Solurion Explorer and, if the new project works as expected, deleting the old project.

Comment: I do have other projects and they all work correctly

Comment: can you please explain or give a link on how to move the items from the old project to the new one?

Comment: It's simple drag and drop within the Solution Explorer. Drag an item to a different project and it will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the Assembly name and RootNamespace in the project properties.

Or drag and drop all items from the original project into the new project.